# What are the differences between Orcs and Uruks?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, orcs

*The Lord of the Rings* trilogy mentions the existence of Orcs and Uruks.

I know that Orcs used to be Elves as Saruman says that **they were once Elves**, but what did Uruks used to be and why are they bigger and better fighters than the Orcs?

What are the differences between Orcs and Uruks?

Comment: Where does Saruman say Orcs used to be Elves?

Comment: @AndresF. In fellowship of the ring saruman told to the uruk-hai leader.

Comment: @AndresF. - it needs to be clarified that this quote is from the movies; it doesn't appear in the books (strictly speaking Jackson was overstepping the bounds of what material he was allowed use by including it).

Comment: @JimmyShelter I thought so. But I asked just in case I was forgetting about something :) I consider the movies non-canon.

Comment: Tolkein makes plenty of allusions, more in the Silmarillion, to the elvish origins of Orcs.  Since Saruman would know of this, I don't think claiming it doesn't exist in the books or that Jackson "overstepped" is accurate.

Comment: Doesn't Gandalf say (movie) that Saruman used some "evil/fell/dark/etc craft" to create Uruks from Orcs and Goblins? That's what I vaguely remember, but it has been a long time since reading/seeing LOTR.

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26725/4918 "What is the true origin of the orcs?" about whether the orcs were once elves or not (we don't really know).

Comment: Trying again.

Tolkien was inconsistent with the origins of Orcs; and he was against it being called a trilogy. It's in the letters and also at least the second edition onward. And the Uruks are from Mordor. It's in the appendix but you can also see it in the Encyclopaedia of Arda: http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/u/uruks.html (Uruk-hai being the full name: http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/m/mordororcs.html)

Comment: @PoloHoleSet You do know though that The Silmarillion had many versions, right? And that he was undecided on this matter (in the letters too)? There were a lot of uncertainties. But let's say that it wasn't an overstep for PJ to do that. What *is an overstep* is having Saruman claim that the Uruk-hai are his (they aren't his and his orcs - if you want to call them that - quarrel with the Uruks in the book). The very fact Uruk is Black Speech should make that obvious but what's obvious isn't so obvious to PJ and neither is canon.

Comment: @Pryftan - you do see that OP asks nothing about Saruman's claims that they are "his," but is focused more on the elvish origin's, and that aspect is what is focused on early in the comments.  However if we want to quibble about Saruman's claims and Uruks, it should be noted that Saruman called his orcs "Uruk-hai," while Uruks seem to reference the Mordor orcs.  Saruman's Uruk-hai were bigger and stronger and while it's been a while since I read the books, I remember the clear implication that Saruman accomplished that by mixing humans into the breeding lineage. See my comment below..

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I was ironically actually talking about the elvish origin you just seem to have missed it - perhaps because I contradicted you? - and thus tell me .. whatever. The fact remains Uruk-hai are the same thing as Uruks. Just because Saruman says something doesn't mean it's true. Uruk is Black Speech and as I noted before that should make it obvious where they come from. But that eluded you, seemingly, despite me pointing that out. Saruman tells falsehoods and half-truths and is also extremely proud and arrogant so of course he's going to make grandiose claims. He had fallen.

Comment: @Pryftan - "What is an overstep is having Saruman claim that the Uruk-hai are his" and "I was ironically actually talking about the elvish origin you just seem to have missed it" - apparently not. Maybe your English is not at your Black Speech level.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I initially did talk about the origins. Reading comprehension please? But I won't continue that part of the conversation with someone who blatantly insults people whilst simultaneously ignoring part of my comment that would contradict your reason for the insult in the first place.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Uruk-Hais are Orcs. Just a special breed, that is stronger, faster and can withstand sunlight. Although Treebeard speculates that Saruman created them by crossbreeding Orcs with men, there is no tangible evidence for that. Nonetheless your average Orc is bow-legged while Uruk-hais have straight legs. Also they are bigger. But as far as we know Uruks are just a subspecies of Orcs.

This is further evidenced by their name: In the Black Speech Uruk-hai means Orc-Folk.

Comment: Their name in which language out of interest?

Comment: @Liath It's the Black Speech. You wouldn't expect less of Sauron, wouldn't you?

Comment: depends who was naming them - thanks for the expansion!

Comment: It's strongly suggested in the books that it's a cross-breed between traditional orcs and humans.  That's also backed up by allusions to men who seem a bit orc-ish as Saruman's muscle when, in the books, he pretty much occupies the Shire after being evicted from Orthanc by Treebeard.

Answer (score 6):

This question is a little bit tricky because it's important to remember that Uruk and Uruk-Hai refer to different things, at least in the dialect of the Isenguard Uruk-Hai. Tolkien was a linguist, and he loved adding this kind of cultural quirk. According to legend, he created Middle Earth, just as a place to simulate these kinds of cultural drifts, changes and misunderstandings.

Isenguard Uruk-Hai are strongly implied (in the book trilogy) to be an abominable hybrid of the races of Orcs and Men, designed by Saruman to have all the strengths of both and none of the weaknesses.

Meanwhile Orc, Uruk, Hobgoblin, Goblin and Snaga (lit. "slave" or "maggot") are all words that refer to members of the Orc race, which was created by the First Dark Lord, Morgoth, in the Pit of Angband.

One character might use one word in particular to refer to any Orc, because of that character's cultural background. Another character might use each of those words selectively, depending on the size, heritage and social status of the orc in question.

Some purebred Orc tribes even go so far as to claim the title of Uruk-Hai for themselves, adding another term for pure Orcs, and further complicating the task of distinguishing between Orcs and Hybrids. In universe, it appears that Saruman actually appropriated the term from them, when indoctrinating his hybrid shock troops, but it still makes things extra confusing.

Comment: No. Snaga is Black Speech. That's from Sauron; it's not from Morgoth.

Comment: And I neglected to mention something else so I'll say it again. Uruk is short for Uruk-hai (or more correctly Uruk-hai = orc people, orc folk). Whatever Saruman claims doesn't equate to reality (neither does the claim it was a trilogy equate to reality for that matter). And to elaborate on my point about Morgoth they aren't members of the 'Orc race'. Uruks are an improvement over Morgoth's Orc and so are the Olog-hai (the trolls) over Morgoth's trolls.  You're right that Saruman confuses things though - for everyone including Sauron. Lots of infighting and Sauron encouraged it too.

Comment: @Pryftan - No.  There is a lot of dispute about that, and it's certainly not considered established fact that Uruk = Uruk-hai.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Funny really. The Encyclopaedia of Arda would agree with me. So would many other sources. Ironically this answer points out the confusion - perhaps you should read it? Saruman once again confuses matters in his own pride and arrogance.

Comment: @Pryftan - Love how you completely ignore the fact that the Isengard orcs have different physical features and capabilities, not just according to Saruman.  "Funny really." Even if we decide that Uruk and Uruk-hai are interchangable, that does not make the Isengard Orcs the same as Mordor Orcs.  Saruman absolutely had his own breeding operation.

Comment: Here is a discussion that covers 36 pages. Certainly not settled. http://www.thetolkienforum.com/index.php?threads/uruks-vs-uruk-hai.2146/

Comment: @PoloHoleSet In fact I didn't ignore that. Your reading comprehension again has failed. I never said that Saruman didn't have his own Orcs. One might also think of the Olog-hai but I guess you're not one of those as far as how they would also come from Mordor. But I'm done with this because you resort to petty insults (as above) when in fact you removed the part I claimed to have stated (in your citing me) and you also put meaning into my comments that had no bearings whatsoever.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I said I wasn't going to continue but I will. With this: In UT CT finally published what Tolkien promised - an index of names/definitions.  And I quote: **Uruks  Anglicized form of Uruk-hai of the Black Speech; a race of Orcs of great size and strength. 357-9, 361** And guess what? That first page references **both Uruks (not Uruk-hai) and Isengarders. So the Uruk-hai and Uruks are related; Isengarders are different.** And in HoME this distinction is also made. So actually it *is settled* to those who bother with checking references that would matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71889/discussion-between-poloholeset-and-pryftan).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, Uruks are simply stronger and faster and can tolerate the sun. I also don't recall it ever being explicitly stated whether this is due to them being a different breed of, or just "better" orcs meaning rank wise, and their stature may be due to what their rank or position in orc society affords. The Uruk-hai on the other hand are definitely a product of Saruman as they are distinct from the other orcs in the raiding party which may or may not have also included Uruks from Mordor and Moria.

Answer (score 1):

Sauron created the black Uruk's, a race of black Orcs that are stronger. This is stated in the appendices of *The Return of the King* when they attack Gondor. *Saruman's* Uruk-Hai are different, slightly. They have straight legs and are likely a cross breed of Men and Orcs. They are very similar to Sauron's Uruks, but different.

They both have Uruk's! Saruman's are called the Uruk-Hai. Sauron's are called the Uruks. They both have black skin.

Answer (score 0):

**Uruk Hai:** Strong, fast, tolerate sun, smart, disciplined, humanly proportional arms, poor eyesight at night

**Regular Orc:** Weak, slow, can't tolerate sun, idiot, undisciplined, longer arms, excellent eyesight at night

I think in the third book, when Sam and Frodo were under disguise, an Uruk was complaining about other orcs and stated all the things I listed here.

Although Saruman claims he perfected orcs, Sauron uses them as well.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is melkor made orcs, and sauron made the uruks. Saruman has uruk-hai but he didn't create them.merely plucked them out of the ground in the movies, also in the movies saruman tells a uruk that orcs were once elves,saruman says the word they. Uruks behave like men and is the most likely answer to their being.the true identity is not known. I have to say I truly believe myself some could be numenoreans, only because in the book the silmarillion numenor fell to the sea. Before it fell sauron in disguise managed to make some them believe in melkor as master of the world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you cite any references for this?  (Especially that Sauron created the Uruk[-Hai].)