# Are orcs considered evil to Eru and the Valar?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, orcs

It's to my understanding that orcs were once elves that were captured and tortured by Morgoth ages ago, becoming what's now orcs. Being captured and tortured is obviously not their fault, therefore are they considered evil by Eru and the Valar? Will they be treated differently compared to men and elves when they die?

Comment: I would assume orcs have no "soul" in the sense that they get an after life. those original elves may have been able to have an afterlife, but current generations of orcs are shown to be pure evil, with no choice for goodness.

Comment: poor little guys...

Comment: This is why Tolkien went back and tried to recast the entire story of how Orcs came about and what they were. He had theological problems accepting the idea that Orcs were evil in themselves.]

Comment: [Relevant](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26725/what-is-the-true-origin-of-the-orcs?rq=1)

Comment: @Himarm If they have "no choice," how can they be evil? That is like calling a destructive tsunami evil, and diminished the concept of evil itself.

Comment: @Lexible - In the standard sense of wanting to cause pain, suffering, and (to some extent) death to others? That’s always been my understanding. Choice never really entered into it. If people move out of the way of a tsunami, it won’t chase them. It has no interest in killing or hurting people, only in moving forward. A ravenous animal will generally not torture its prey, or kill more than it needs to survive (and if it does, then that’s evil to an extent). Evil doesn’t need a profound philosophical commitment, it just needs the goals of evil.

Comment: @Adamant Not sure where you are going with that. A tsunami does not have destruction as a goal, but destruction is epiphenomenal to it. If orcs do not have free will, then their destructiveness is epiphenomenal to their existence. The ability to choose good (godly) or evil—i.e. free will—is critically important to the Catholicism of Tolkien. If orcs cannot choose to be good (instead of evil), then they aren't evil; they simply exist destructively.

Comment: @Lexible - I’m not really thinking about how Catholicism views evil here. I know that the problem of how orcs could be evil without having free will greatly concerned Tolkien, and that was, as you say, related to his Catholic faith; the two just don’t seem particularly synonymous to *me*.

Comment: @Adamant That's great! Unfortunately, individual opinions are not the purview of SciFi/Fantasy SE. Tolkien's opinions, however, are spot on important to the OP's question.

Comment: @Lexible - Ah, my mistake. It seemed you and Himarm were sharing your personal opinions about what evil was. Perhaps a reference to Tolkien should have been somewhere in your or Himarm's comments if that was what you meant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tolkien's final thoughts on Orcs are contained in the "Orcs" essays in *Myths Transformed*, published in *History of Middle-earth 10: Morgoth's Ring*.  There are several passages there that have bearing on this question, but — as may be expected — the question of what exactly the origin of Orcs is will also influence the answer.

One discussion in these texts explores the possibility of Orcs being ultimately redeemable:

> But Men had not yet appeared, when the Orcs already existed.  Aulë constructed the Dwarves out of his memory of the Music; but Eru would not sanction the work of Melkor so as to allow the independence of the Orcs. (Not unless Orcs were ultimately remediable, or could be amended and 'saved'?)

Another part of the same text explores the possibility of Orcs as being originally some kind of spirit-being, such as lesser Maiar:

> ...they would become more and more earthbound, unable to return to spirit-state (even demon-form), until released by death (killing), and they would dwindle in force. When released they would, of course, like Sauron, be 'damned': i.e. reduced to impotence, infinitely recessive: still hating but unable more and more to make it effective physically (or would not a very dwindled dead Orc-state be a poltergeist?)

A third part discusses the fate of Orcs-as-Elves:

> It remains therefore terribly possible there was an Elvish strain in the Orcs. These may then even have been mated with beasts (sterile!) — and later Men. Their life-span would be diminished.  And dying they would go to Mandos and be held in prison till the End.

And a fourth puts forward the theory that Orcs were parts of Melkor/Morgoth's distributed spirit (in which case they'll share the same fate as him):

> It will there be seen that the wills of Orcs and Balrogs etc. are part of Melkor's power 'dispersed'.

A further and later text, where Tolkien provides support for the theory of Orcs-as-Men also mentions a fate for them:

> But even before this wickedness of Morgoth was suspected the Wise in the Elder Days taught always that the Orcs were not 'made' by Melkor, and therefore were not in their origin evil. They might have become irredeemable (at least by Elves and Men), but they remained within the Law.

---

So ultimately the question of whether or not they can be redeemed depends on their origin.

Since you ask with specific reference to the origin given in the published *Silmarillion*, the answer is given in the third quotation above: they are held in Mandos until the End, but Tolkien does not speculate on what may happen to them after.

It's notable that being held in Mandos until the End is the same fate as that given for evil-doing Elves in the essay entitled "Of re-birth and other dooms of those that go to Mandos" (part of *Laws and Customs among the Eldar*, also published in *Morgoth's Ring*):

> The Shadow upon Arda caused not only misfortune and injury to the body. It could corrupt the mind; and those among the Eldar who were darkened in spirit did unnatural deeds, and were capable of hatred and malice. Not all who died suffered innocently [...] Of the others, the wrong-doers, many were held long in 'waiting', and **some were not permitted to take up their lives again**.

The answer is therefore clear: within the scope of your question (Orcs-as-Elves) **they are considered evil by the Valar, and have the same fate as evil-doing Elves**, but Tolkien doesn't speculate as to their fate beyond the end of the world (nor does he do so for Elves), which leaves the question of how Ilúvatar views them open.  For other origins, they may or may not have different fates.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26725/4918 "What is the true origin of the orcs?"