# Did the description of Grendel influence Tolkien's depiction of the Orcs?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, orcs, beowulf

Since Tolkien was largely influenced by the Old English poem *Beowulf*, it should not be a surprise if his Orcs were at least partly derived from it.

Just as the Orcs are twisted, monstrous, naturally evil descendants of Elves, so is  Grendel a twisted, monstrous, naturally evil descendant of Cain, and thus Adam. There is a similar motif of mundane beings being corrupted into monsters.

Furthermore, one descendent of Cain mentioned in the poem is referred to to as an **orcneas**.

Comment: Tolkien didn't just read Beowulf, he wrote a [translation and an extensive commentary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf:_A_Translation_and_Commentary). I'd be astounded if his orcs weren't at least partially influenced by this work, generally cited as being the single most important work of Old English literature.

Comment: He described Beowulf as being one of the key influences on his writing of *The Hobbit*; ***As for the rest of the tale it is, as the Habit suggests, derived from (previously digested) epic, mythology, and fairy-story – not, however, Victorian in authorship, as a rule to which George Macdonald is the chief exception. Beowulf is among my most valued sources; though it was not consciously present to the mind in the process of writing, in which the episode of the theft arose naturally (and almost inevitably) from the circumstances.***

Comment: This is not only a Q&A site, we also do literary analysis here!

Comment: @Reginald O'Donoghue It should be pointed out that there is no official word within the Middle-earth legendarium about the origin of Orcs. In the Silmarilion the origin of the Orcs from captured Elves is presented as a theory, not as word of Eru.  Tolkien considered many ideas about the Orcish origins without deciding on one.  There should be a question about the origin on Orcs on this site. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26725/what-is-the-true-origin-of-the-orcs

Comment: @Valorum - The "commentary" in that book is assembled by Christopher Tolkien, using excerpts from Tolkien's lecture notes to two different series of lectures. I'd say what's significant here is that Tolkien spent a few decades lecturing on Beowulf and authored what's arguably the most influential essay on it, not that his son posthumously edited some of his notes into a book.

Answer (score 21):

Unlikely, since Tolkien was professor of Old English (and as Valorum commented, wrote a translation and commentary on Beowulf). The Old English word "orc" corresponds with Latin Orcus (deity of the Underworld), and synonymous with the Norse þyrs/ðyrs "ogre", so it has a different mythological origin than Grendel, and Tolkien would certainly have been aware of that.

Grendel is referred to in *Beowulf* as a *sceadugenga* – shadow-walker, night-goer. Orcs are mentioned apart from Grendel in lines 111–114 in *Beowulf*:

> Þanon untydras ealle onƿocon
>   eotenas ond ylfe ond **orcneas**
>   sƿylce gigantas þa ƿið gode ƿunnon
>   lange þrage he him ðæs lean forgeald
>
> *Thence all evil broods were born,
>
>   ogres and elves and **orcs**
>
>   —the giants also, who long time fought with God,
>
>   for which he gave them their reward*

Tolkien's Orc origins are first described in *The Tale of Tinúviel* as "foul broodlings of Melkor who fared abroad doing his evil work".

See also: [Origins of Orcs in Middle-Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orc_(Middle-earth)#The_origin_of_Orcs)

Comment: Tolkien translated line 112 as "ogres and goblins and **haunting shapes of hell**" (on page 16 of the version published by CJRT, lines 90-91)

Answer (score 4):

To quote from Tolkien's "Commentary accompanying the translation of *Beowulf*", published by Christopher Tolkien and based on Tolkien senior's lecture notes from the 1930s (as the Professor of Anglo Saxon at Oxford, per Codosaur's answer):

> 90–1 *haunting shapes of hell*; *112  *orcnéas*
>
> The O.E. word occurs only here. *orc* is found glossing Latin *Orcus* [Hell, Death]. *neas* seems certainly to be *né-as*, plural of the old (poetic) word *né* 'dead body'. This appears also in *né-fugol* 'carrion bird'. Its original stem in Germanic was *nawi-s*: Gothic *naus* (plural *naweis*), Old Norse *ná-r*.
>
> 'Necromancy' will suggest something of the horrible associations of this word. I think that what is here meant is that terrible northern imagination to which I have ventured to give the name 'barrow-wights'. The 'undead'. Those dreadful creatures that inhabit tombs and mounds. They are not living: they have left humanity, but they are 'undead'. With superhuman strength and malice they can strangle men and rend them. Glámr in the story of Grettir the Strong is a well-known example. (Tolkien, *Beowulf, A Translation and Commentary* pp 163–4)

Based on these associations that Tolkien gives to *orcnéas* (at least at the time when this commentary was written), especially the explicit suggestion of barrow-wights, I think it is safe to say that while the **word** *orcnéas*, or even the latin *orcus* may have been a source for Tolkien's 'orc' (which he emphasises is not associated with [Orca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_whale)), the *orcnéas* as **creatures** are not themselves the prototypes for his Legendarium orcs.